# Enable/Disable availability tests in Azure on Schedule

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to run scheduled automation commands in Azure.

I managed to write Enable/Disable command for availability tests both in

Azure CLI:

```
az resource update --set properties.enabled=true --name 'someName' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Insights/webtests' --resource-group 'soemResourceGroup'
```

and

Powershell:

```
#Get All webTests
$resourceGroupnames = "someGroupName1", "someGroupName2";
$enableTests = "True";

ForEach ($resourceGroupname in $resourceGroupnames) { 
    $resourceGroupname
    $allAvailabilityTestsIds = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupname `
    | Where-Object -Property ResourceType -EQ "microsoft.insights/webtests" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceId;

    ForEach ($availabilityTestId in $allAvailabilityTestsIds) { 
        $availabilityTest = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $availabilityTestId;
        $availabilityTest.Properties.Enabled = $enableTests;
        $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
    }
}
```

problem is that I'm not sure to run them outside of Comamnd line and on schedule. I've read that I could use Automation account to use powershell scripts but that seems a nightmare since I got tons of issues with authentication (not sure why).

Is that an only way ?

**EDIT:**
I post the errror I was/am getting below.

```
Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet

Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet

Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet

Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet

Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet

Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet

Set-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Sku'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument 
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:37 char:29
+         $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Azure...dels.PSResource:PSObject) [Set-AzureRmResource], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetAzureResourceCmdlet
```

Regards.

Comment: @JoyWang hello I posted the error message in the post. Like I mentioned before this is working when using Azure Command Line. This error is thrown only when using the runbook. Thanks for interest and help :)

Comment: Did you import the `AzureRM.Resources` module with the latest version? If not, try to unimport it and import it again with the latest version.

Comment: The issue was with module versioning! Thanks a lot for the help. Still I'd think scheduling should be a simple thing. I don't know why they made it so hard in Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow the steps as below to use the azure runbook in automation to do that.

1.Navigate to your automation account -> `Runbooks` -> `Create a runbook` -> create a `Powershell` runbook.

2.In the runbook, add the script to login, your complete script should be like below. (Before running the runbook, make sure you have imported the `AzureRM.Resources` and `AzureRM.Profile` powershell module in your automation account -> `Modules`, if not, in the `Modules` -> `Browse Gallery`, search for the modules and import them.)

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

#Get All webTests
$resourceGroupnames = "someGroupName1", "someGroupName2";
$enableTests = "True";

ForEach ($resourceGroupname in $resourceGroupnames) { 
    $resourceGroupname
    $allAvailabilityTestsIds = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupname `
    | Where-Object -Property ResourceType -EQ "microsoft.insights/webtests" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceId;

    ForEach ($availabilityTestId in $allAvailabilityTestsIds) { 
        $availabilityTest = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $availabilityTestId;
        $availabilityTest.Properties.Enabled = $enableTests;
        $availabilityTest | Set-AzureRmResource -Force;
    }
}
```

3.After running the script successfully, follow this link [**Scheduling a runbook in Azure Automation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules) to add a schedule to your runbook.